# Python numerical solution to an exponential function with two variables

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods, numerical-computing

I have an exponential function with two known variables,  x, and y. I need to find the value of y when I input an x. However, my code could not go through and solve the problem. 
My function and all relevant constants are given below:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

x1=np.array([0,20])

Vt = 0.026
Io = 23*math.pow(10,-10)
Iph = 2.282
idf = 1
Ns = 60 
Nm = 1 
Rse = 0.5
Rsh = 1000
x = np.linspace(x1.min(),x1.max(),300)    
def equation(x,Iph,Io,Rse,Rsh,Ns,Nm,Vt):
    return y - Iph + Io*(np.exp((x+y*Rse)/(Ns*Nm*idf*Vt))-1) + x/Rsh + y*Rse/Rsh 
y = optimize.newton(equation(10,Iph,Io,Rse,Rsh,Ns,Nm,Vt), 7)
```

Present output:

```
 File "<ipython-input-172-93ede88c9b49>", line 16, in ivcurve_equation
    return y - Iph + Io*(np.exp((x+y*Rse)/(Ns*Nm*idf*Vt))-1) + v/Rsh + I*Rse/Rsh 

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Expected output:

```
y = a real and positive value # >0
```

Comment: can you let me know which one is a list or sequence in this line `return y - Iph + Io*(np.exp((x+y*Rse)/(Ns*Nm*idf*Vt))-1) + v/Rsh + I*Rse/Rsh `

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola Please, I edited equation correctly now. Yes! both x and y are lists. But, at the moment I am inputing one x value. I am trying to find value of y for that x.

Comment: def equation(x,Iph,Io,Rse,Rsh,Ns,Nm,Vt):
    return y - Iph + Io*(np.exp((x+y*Rse)/(Ns*Nm*idf*Vt))-1) + x/Rsh + y*Rse/Rsh 

In this method, where y is coming from?

Comment: and also `v`...?

Comment: @Alexander  it was a typo. sorry for that. I edited for that.

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola That's! right. y is the value of variable that I need to find. True that I could not make `y` part of function variables or maybe I am defining the function wrongly.

Comment: if there is no variable inside the function, then how come you are subtracting something from that? Your code is not correct I suppose. You can share a snip of the code you are running.

Comment: Basically I am trying to solve 'y - Iph + Io*(np.exp((x+y*Rse)/(Ns*Nm*idf*Vt))-1) + x/Rsh + y*Rse/Rsh =0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a quick look at the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html#scipy.optimize.newton) and try to do some 'pattern matching'. The parameters of `equation` should only be variables and not constants. Here is a working version of your code, that you should tailor to your needs:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

x1=np.array([0,20])

Vt = 0.026
Io = 23*math.pow(10,-10)
Iph = 2.282
idf = 1
Ns = 60
Nm = 1
Rse = 0.5
Rsh = 1000
x_arr = np.linspace(x1.min(),x1.max(),300)
x = x_arr[0]
def equation(y):
    return y - Iph + Io*(np.exp((x+y*Rse)/(Ns*Nm*idf*Vt))-1) + x/Rsh + y*Rse/Rsh

result = optimize.newton(equation, 7)

print(result)
```

Now if you want the output for an array of x's try this:

```
def equation(y,x):
    return y - Iph + Io*(np.exp((x+y*Rse)/(Ns*Nm*idf*Vt))-1) + x/Rsh + y*Rse/Rsh

result = [optimize.newton(equation, 7, args = (a,)) for a in x_arr]

print(result)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! it worked. I have a question. Whether inputing `fprime`, `fprime2` helps above equation in any way?

Comment: Regarding `fprime` and `fprime2`: Sure, it helps. The newton method converges better, if the first and second derivatives are set, but the tricky part is calculating them. Regarding the array question: I will update my answer